# Accessing backing composite fields in backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I implemented BalusC's answer to the question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-list-with-a-jsf-2-0-composite-component?rq=1) where a composite component displays a list of labels/values.

What I'm looking for is to get in the backing bean the list of values that may have been entered by the user.

I added to the composite component an additional button to submit the values entered in the list:

```
<composite:attribute name="action" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />
```

The form submits well, but I'm not able to figure out how to retrieve the list of values and make them available in the backing bean (Bean.fields list in BalusC's example).

Any ideas?

Comment: JSF already does that all by itself. Are you saying that you get an empty list when you inspect `fields` in the action method?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that JSF does that by itself, I double checked and it works correctly. Thanks again.