# How to update the attribute of composite component?

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have to create a composite component in which there are 3 things.

A text box(1) along with a button(2). And there is a data table(3) below to that text area.

So If user enter something in text area and click button the entered text is added into data table as a new row. So how can I perform this add functionality? And the list which is bind to data table is being passed as attribute in composite component.

What approach I am having currently is to use "componentType" attribute to bind java class to it. But how can I pass this List attribute to get updated?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6358066

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I will look over that link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a dynamic list with a JSF 2.0 Composite Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-list-with-a-jsf-2-0-composite-component)