# binding="#{cc.table}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'cc' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I am trying reproduce the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358066/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-list-with-a-jsf-2-0-composite-component), but in the `dynamicFieldList.xhtml` the `#{cc.table}` is not detected and I have the following error:

```
/WEB-INF/tags/dynamicFieldList.xhtml @17,93 binding="#{cc.table}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'cc' resolved to null
```

Below is the line of code

```
<ui:composition
...
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
...

<cc:implementation>

    <h:dataTable id="table" binding="#{cc.table}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="field">

        <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{field.label}" /></h:column>

        // ...
</cc:implementation>

...
```

probably linked to the same issue but label and value Strings in the outputLabel from the "Field" Class are not detected as well. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: A composite component is not a tagfile. Hover the [composite-component] tag below the question until a popover shows up and then click therein *info* link.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in your error message doesn't look right.

> /WEB-INF/tags/dynamicFieldList.xhtml

Composite components doesn't belong there. You seem to have treated the composite component as a tagfile. This is not right. It's very different from a tagfile. Composite components are supposed to be placed in JSF `/resources` folder in a subfolder representing the library name. The below example uses `components` as library name.

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- resources
 |    `-- components
 |         `-- dynamicFieldList.xhtml   <--- Here.
 `-- some.xhtml
```

Also you don't need to declare them in a `*.taglib.xml` file as you would do  for tagfiles. You can just declare them via implicit `http://java.sun.com/composite/[libraryName]` XML namespace.

```
<html ... xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/composite/components">
...
<my:dynamicFieldList ... />
```

#### See also:

- [Our composite component wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: Thanks for your time. As my clientID issue for ajax change remain unsolved I will post another question for that. I manually created the nested table and subtable with <c:forEach> but I still can't update the column next by...

Answer (score 0):

My expectation of a Content Assist at this location inside a composite-component implementation is not possible.

By creating the following folder: WebContent > resources > mycomponents where I placed my composite-component solved my issue.